# Stack smashing protection (Load ESP from stack)

Tags: buffer-overflow

Kind of new into the area, today I was experimenting with some challenges on buffer overflows and I found a prevention technique that I could not identify.
Basically, they had the stack address restored from a value that was stored directly above the local arguments in the stack. (So overwriting the the local variables, would make the return into controlled code difficult when aslr is on)

The epilogue was:

```
pop    ecx
lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
ret
```

I found it pretty hard to bypass when there is no access to indirect memory access, so I was looking for the protector suite/technique name in order to make some research on it.

It seems that it can be only effectively bypassed when aslr is off, since the user cannot set the stack into one of his controlled areas.

Comment: I don't think this is a protection - it's just gcc aligning the stack in the main function. You'll probably see esp being saved to ecx in the prologue, and then `and esp, -8`. It seems to happen when you compile with `-m32` on 64-bit or if you increase the `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` flag.

Comment: I've verified what you said, but nevertheless, this turns out to be a pretty good protection defense.

Comment: @JakeNuktis I agree with grc that's it's simply stack alignment.  GCC usually only performs this on the `main` function once to align the program.  I'm not sure if you could force it for every function or not.  It's not normal to manipulate the stack pointer that way, and doing so in every function will mean needing to account for parameters passed into functions.